# Convert fork implementation to pthread implementation

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to transform this code that uses fork() to thread. Because i need the variable value to change.

Code using fork():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int value = 5;
int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){ //child process
        printf("Entrei no filho! \n");
        value += 15;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(pid > 0){ //parent process
        wait(NULL);
        printf("PARENT: value = %d\n", value);
        return 0;
    }}
```

The final value is 5

My attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    char *msg1 = "First thread";
    char *msg2 = "Second thread";
    int value = 5;

    pthread_create(thread1, NULL, if1, (void *) msg1);
    pthread_create(thread2, NULL, if2, (void *) msg2);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    return 0;
}
void *if1(){
    value += 15;
    return NULL;
}
void *if2(){
    printf("Final value: %d",value);
    return NULL;
}
```

The final value has to be 20 using threads

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: going to need to add some protection around `value` and make it visible to your thread functions, and your thread functions need a `void*` parameter.

Comment: In your code it is possible that thread2 will start first and print out the `Final value: ...` before thread1 starts.  Of course it is also possible that thread1 will start first and update value before thread2 starts.  And finally, on a multi-processor system, it is possible that both threads are running simultaneously and thread2 will print out some weird value.  You need to protect the variable `value` with a mutex of some sort. Also, you need to figure out a way to have the threads run in whatever order you want them to run, if that's a requirement.

Comment: I agree with @klutt. What is the problem? This is the fundamental difference between processes and threads. Threads share the heap and global data but have their own stacks, whereas processes have their own address spaces. What is the problem with creating an array of values, one for each thread, or simply stacking the value inside of each thread? You would essentially be creating a new copy of value when you fork anyway (since you are create an entire new copy of the old program).